# react-router-dom with Vite can't be build

Tags: node.js, npm, vite, rollupjs, build-error

I have finished my React project with Vite, but when I build the project with npm run build the terminal throw me this error:

[vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "react-router-dom" from "C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/Portfolio/my_portfolio/portfolio/src/App.jsx".
This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
`build.rollupOptions.external`
error during build:
Error: [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "react-router-dom" from "C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/Portfolio/my_portfolio/portfolio/src/App.jsx".
This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
`build.rollupOptions.external`
at onRollupWarning (file:///C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/Portfolio/my_portfolio/portfolio/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-ca21228b.js:44792:19)
at onwarn (file:///C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/Portfolio/my_portfolio/portfolio/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-ca21228b.js:44562:13)
at Object.onwarn (file:///C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/Portfolio/my_portfolio/portfolio/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:25097:13)
at ModuleLoader.handleInvalidResolvedId (file:///C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/Portfolio/my_portfolio/portfolio/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:23779:26)
at file:///C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/Portfolio/my_portfolio/portfolio/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:23739:26
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

I search this error but I don't see anything that helps me, I don't know what i have to do.

Comment: Did you install `react-router-dom` properly? Check your `package.json` file, if it contains a reference to this package. Also check whether you're having mutliple `package.json`-files; there should only be one for your project. Yet npm generates a new one, if you install in the wrong working directory.

Comment: I install react-router-dom correctly i think, with npm install react-router-dom command, the version in the package.json is 6.2.1 and I have only one package.json in my project. What should I do?

Comment: I resolve it, the answer is use the comand npm install react-router-dom --save